# How to retrieve the resource list in the openstack compute engine?

Tags: openstack

Unfortunately I have deleted "keystone" database in my openstack environment. After that I configured all the services, but the existing resources like server, network, snapshot, volume are not listed in the dashboard.

Through terminal the images are listed properly.

Can anyone say how to retrieve this list back?[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you restart horizon? Also try logging in from a different browser or in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Once the keystone database was deleted in mysql, It cannot not identify the existing resources under Project -> admin page.

Go to opensatck home page, on the left side there are four services listed, select "System" tab and navigate to any one of the resource page, now the existing resource got displayed properly. I performed some actions like restart and stop servers, they are working fine.

I think a new "identify service" is created. So the service id changed and couldn't identify their own resources. Existing service id is stored on their own database like images(glance) , server(nova), network(neutron), so the resource are listed without project name under "System" -> page.